# JAI Image Adjustment Bottlenecks

Tags: java, image, resize, jai, slowdown

I'm using the JAI library to do adjustments on a series of images, each about 1300x1000 in size.  I adjust pixel intensities with "Rescale" and add text and lines with the Graphics2D object from the TiledImage.createGraphics() method.  Then I resize the image to fit the screen with "subsampleaverage" and render to screen with Graphics2D.drawRenderedImage().  Up to this point, there is little slowdown, with rendering taking about 40-60 milliseconds.

However, if I only add the text and lines, the display slows down to 100-200 milliseconds.  I can't seem to figure out why this is, as adding the text after or before adjust pixel intensities is fine.

I've been searching through the site, but I can't seem to find any concrete answer.  Many suggestions have been to use BufferedImages, but converting from PlanarImages to BufferedImages seems to also have a slowdown issue.

Comment: To anyone with this problem, I suggest using JOGL for display and resizing.  After fiddling with JAI and JOGL, I've been able to fix most of the slowdown issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently text is still rendered very slowly in Java.  The glyphs for each `Font` object has to be rendered and painted on the `Graphics` object.  With a lot of text on the object, the `Font` object along with all the used `Glyphs` are recreated, causing a massive slowdown.

Even using JOGL, there is a significant slowdown.  But using the same `TextRenderer` object alleviates this by creating a single `Font` object and reusing it as long as the `TextRenderer` is alive.  Of course, this restricts you from using multiple Font objects, as JOGL has yet to implement a `setFont` function, requiring you to create a new `TextRenderer` object for each new font, font style, and font weight.

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues.